# how to select array in postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have json like this (in my databases) ==>

```json
[
  {
   "name": "Shahin",
   "biography": "I am an Iranian person to Persian rap \n",
   "is_private": false,
  }
]
```

now I want to get "Shahin", any help would be appreciated.

‌

Comment: Your JSON value is an array. What is the output you expect if that array contains hundreds of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this

```
SELECT id,(val->>'name')
FROM your_table_name, 
     jsonb_array_elements(YOURCOLUMN) val
```